# Book with tesseracts Story ID

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

I read this book in 2007 but it was a old book (1960s I believe) and it was about these kids who met these 3 old ladies with names like "What" ,"Who" and another one. They find out their father is on a planet and use a tesseract to teleport there. They find out he is trapped on this world with the "Thing" and that "Thing" was slowly overtaking every planet and Earth was getting close to being taken over. I would really like to know the title and any help is nice. Even if you don't really think it matches a title would be appreciated.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Are you thinking of [A Wrinkle in Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time) by Madeleine L'Engle?

[image: Book cover]

It follows Meg Murry, Charles Wallace, and Calvin O'Keefe who are transported via tesseract by Mrs Whatsit, Mrs Who, and Mrs Which.

Comment: Beat me to it, one of my faves from when I was a kid.

Comment: Begins with the famous bit of purple prose, "[It was a dark and stormy night ...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_was_a_dark_and_stormy_night)" :)

Comment: I didn't remember there was a tesseract. But I enjoyed it when I read it.

Comment: @WayneWerner Just off the question title I immediately thought of *A Wrinkle in Time*. The tesseract is one of the main plot elements in the book.

Comment: IIRC, the Mesdames Who, Which, and Whatsit all used to be stars. Like the giant balls of burning gas: stars.

Comment: @EngineerToast - Actually, while that is probably true, we only actually know for a fact that Mrs. Whatsit is a former star. The rest are assumed to be by association. They are all angels.

Comment: That is it! Thanks. @EvSunWoodard oh yeah!

Comment: The three old ladies represent the [Moirai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moirai) or [Norns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norns), as I recall.

Answer (score 21):

This is *[A Wrinkle in Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time)* by Madeline L'Engle.

It's the first of a series called *[Time Quintet](http://www.madeleinelengle.com/books/time-quintet/)*:

1. A Wrinkle in Time (1962)
2. A Wind in the Door (1973)
3. A Swiftly Tilting Planet (1978)
4. Many Waters (1986)
5. An Acceptable Time (1989)

Comment: Alas, when I read it there were only two.