# Sci-fi book, a girl who can "tesseract" (teleport), she and a boy try to see what the people with this ability can do, are stopped by the mother

Tags: story-identification, books

A friend of mine is trying to remember a book that they read part of once, probably about ten or more years ago. They used the word "tesseract" to mean "teleport".

> The cover was green, with like, light green lines over it. The characters, no. But it was about this kid and he was a product of a dr and this chick who could tesseract and they were trying to see what all these people with this ability could do and the mom did this thing that ended it and I want to know wtf she did
>
> Anyway, they were being watched and tesseracting was like, not allowed. But this kid ended up losing his sneaker in mud bc he was late and dicking around
>
> And so, surely this will get these people who were watching them to come at them but I didn't get that far, either.
>
> It's one of those that does like, different views per chapter. It was such a cool book...

---

Please note that it isn't *A Wrinkle in Time*.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already, but if your friend could take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories to [edit] in, that'd be cool! Anything might help - by the way, why does "tesseract" mean here? Is it related to [the geometry notion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract) and/or [its Marvel counterpat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_Cube)?

Comment: When asked what they meant by "tesseract" they said "teleport"
Also they said they remembered it from about 10 years ago so it's at least that old.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151160/book-with-tesseracts-story-id?

Comment: Chicks tend to prefer not to be called chicks, in my experience.

Comment: Saw that post, it is not A Wrinkle in Time.
And her words not mine like I said that is just the description they gave me lol. I too am not fan of the term "chick" generally.

Comment: You don't need to tell us about an edit, the system already maintains its own [edit history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/205983/revisions)

Comment: Still got a question on taht tesseract thing - is it a term _your friend_ used/coined, or is said friend reasonably sure that very word was used in the book? (by the way, you can notify other users that you replied to their comments with an @ - `@Jenayah When asked...`. This way, users will get an inbox notification)

Comment: @Jenayah Best I can tell it was the term used in the book.

Comment: You said that it isn't A Wrinkle in Time.  But could it be one of the sequels?

Comment: @ArcanistLupus The sequels to *A Wrinkle in Time* do not involve tesseracts.  However, given that a tesseract is really just another word for a hypercube, the use of the word to denote a form a form of teleportation seems like an almost sure sign that the author was influenced by *A Wrinkle in Time*.

Comment: @Buzz I'll admit that I only read one of the sequels (the one with the mitochondrial mice?) before deciding that they were a bit too weird for my tastes.